# Looping through specific worksheet in folder full of excel files and extract as .csv

Tags: vba

I'm trying to save a folder of excel sheets as .csv. However, I only able to save the .csv of the active sheet. Would it be possible to specify which sheet within these folder of excel files that I would like to extra it from?

Thank you so much !

Where should I put the sheetname in my code to specify that the looping should only occur for that particular sheet? Thank you!

```
'Loop through each Excel file in folder
  Do While myFile <> ""
    'Set variable equal to opened workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & myFile)
    nameWb = myPath & Left(myFile, InStr(1, myFile, ".") - 1) & ".csv"
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=nameWb, FileFormat:=xlCSV
    ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False
    'Get next file name
      myFile = Dir
  Loop
```

Comment: did you ever try my solution. I realize it was awhile ago, but I'm pretty sure it will work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing roughly the same in my project. I copy the WS I want to save to a new WB, and then save the new file.

```
    Workbooks(ExportFile).Worksheets(ExportSheet).Copy
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "path/" & ExportSheet & ".txt", FileFormat:=xlCSV
```

As far as I know, making copies of the worksheets is the only way of saving specific worksheets.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to loop through the sheets. You basically probably are going to test if the name matches your pre-determined list. You could also use error checking for named ranges, or a wide variety of other ways to flag which sheets to use.

```
'define variables
Dim wb As Workbook, WS As Worksheet
      Do While myFile <> ""
        'Set variable equal to opened workbook


        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & myFile)


        'Here's the loop you are looking for I think
        For Each WS In wb.Worksheets

            'OR statements/If statements can be used.
            'Also lookout for name syntax being case-sensative. You might
            'want to include Ucase on both sides to defend against inconsistencies.

            If WS.Name = "LetsDoThisSheet!" Or UCase(WS.Name) = UCase("AndThisone2") Then

                WS.Visible = xlSheetVisible
                WS.Activate
                nameWb = myPath & Left(myFile, InStr(1, myFile, ".") - 1) & ".csv"
                ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=nameWb, FileFormat:=xlCSV
                ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False


            End If

        Next WS


        'Get next file name
          myFile = Dir
      Loop
```